# Entity Framework, repository and Linq? Load just an entity or also child nodes?

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, repository, repository-pattern, poco

I am new to Entity Framework and I want to get some points about the constellation EF, LINQ, POCOs and repositories.

We have a working solution with a repository which uses EF and POCOs to access the database. We are doing all our queries in LINQ through the context. We added the mapping into mapping classes which are loaded at the application start as the database/tables are already existing.

If I have a business case where I need to calculate for a specific company the amount of toys bought by the employees for their children.

How would I build up the repository / repositories?

A: call with one repository all employees of a company and then call in the service layer again another repo for every employee the children and so on?

B: call one repository which returns me the company with all employees, children and the toys?

A seems to me much cleaner and I can reuse the repositories more often. But B seams to be the more efficient but not reusable so much. Less repositories and the queries would get bigger and bigger.

That is just a small example... but we have much larger business cases. What is the best architectural approach in this case?

```
class Company
{
    List<Employee> employees;
}

class Employee
{
    List<Child> children;
}

class Child
{
    List<Toy> toys;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a repository? Can't you just use your ORM directly? All those concerns go away immediately.

Comment: We added the Repo to seperate the DBaccess / ORM from the business logic.

Comment: The ORM *is* that separation already.

Comment: yeah but what if we would like to switch from EF to nHibernate?

Comment: You won't. You app depends on EF in many subtle ways. You just don't realize. Also, you don't need to use both of them at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call repository to get company, employee, children and toys!

> I need to calculate for a specific Company the amount of Toys bought by the employees for there children

So your business case is to have a single number or maybe number per toy or number per employee. You don't need to load all those entities and compute it in your application. You just need to write an aggregation query (either in Linq or SQL). This whole computation is supposed to run in the database.

If you need to hide the query behind the repository simply choose one where this business case belongs and expose the query as a new method for the repository.

Comment: The question is here when does aggregation queries become business logic? If I would extend it to have a toy-price table and would like to calculate the cost. would u still use aggregation queries? For me it sounds a little bit like doing business logic /calculation at the data access layer. isnt it so?

Comment: Query is part of business logic. It doesn't matter that you execute it in database - you define it in business logic and you use it to achieve the logic. If you are going it the way you initially described your application will have terrible performance on small data sets and it will be useless on large data sets.

Comment: If I ask other architectural awear guys they will tell me that the query is not part of the business logic but the business logic requires the query to get the data. The idea with loading all the required at once is nice. I got ur point!

Comment: Would u try to do all the possible calculations with the linq2SQL? When do u start to do logic in the service?

Comment: When it is logic which needs .NET code to compute. If it is just aggregation query there is no reason to collect all data in your application to compute the result.

Answer (score 0):

While there is never a hard and fast rule, to me using a single unit of work for each of your aggregate roots (In your example, Company) seems to work the most consistently to keep things organized, and prevent concurrency errors since it will handle all the wiring up, and managing of your objects.  There is [a great MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) post on what a unit of work is. An excerpt from that article:

> In a way, you can think of the Unit of Work as a place to dump all
>   transaction-handling code. The responsibilities of the Unit of Work
>   are to:
>
> - Manage transactions.
> - Order the database inserts, deletes, and    updates.
> - Prevent duplicate updates. Inside a single usage of a Unit    of Work object, different parts of the code may mark the same Invoice
>     object as changed, but the Unit of Work class will only issue a
>     single UPDATE command to the database.
>
> The value of using a Unit of Work pattern is to free the rest of your
>   code from these concerns so that you can otherwise concentrate on
>   business logic.

There are several blog posts about this, but the best one I've found is on how to implement it is [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).   There are some other ones which have been referred to from this site [here](http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/), and [here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/12/15/entity-framework-ef4-generic-repository-and-unit-of-work-prototype/).

> A seems to me much cleaner and I can reuse the Repositories more
>   often. But B seams to be the more efficient but not reusable so much.
>   less repositories and the queries would get bigger and bigger.

Generic repositories handle your concerns here, making it easy to create a repo for each of your data objects, while making it reusable and easily testable.  Then your business logic can just be handled in a service layer in your unit of work ensuring that you don't have concurrency issues.

Comment: The MSDN post helped me to get some points about the Unit of Work which we are already using in the service layer.